# Convergence criteria for scipy.eigvalsh

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

I am using python (scipy) to compute eigenvalues of a symmetric real matrix.  I am currently using the

```
scipy.linalg.eigvalsh
```

function to compute the eigenvalues (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvalsh.html#scipy.linalg.eigvalsh).  Looking at the source code for eigvalsh it appears that python makes a call to a fortran package.  It also mentions, in the documentation, that an error will be thrown in the computation does not converge.

My question is: what is the convergence criteria? and can I change it (relatively easily)?

In my specific application I compute the eigenvalues of a sequence of matrices and I am noticing strong correlation between several of the eigenvalues.  I want to know if the correlation is not perfect purely because of numerical reasons.  If I can strengthen the convergence criteria then I can see if the dependence increases.

Answer (score 1):

If I read the source code right, the LAPACK function [dsyevr()](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d3b/dsyevr_8f.html) is used. If I understand it right, fiddling with its parameters will not necessarily get you a higher accuracy. If you need high accuracy, you could try [mpmath](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/mpmath/index.html):

```
import numpy as np
from mpmath import mp

print("*** Scipy calculations: ***")
# Generate matrix:
n = 25
AA = np.random.randn(n, n)
HH = np.dot(AA, AA.T)

# Calculate eigenvalues and -vectors:
w, VV = eigh(HH)  # eigvalsh() calls also eigh()

# Check Result:
HH2 = np.dot(VV, np.diag(w).dot(VV.T))
dHH = HH - HH2
elem_diff_max = np.abs(HH-HH2).max()
print("Elements differ by maximally {}".format(np.abs(dHH).max()))
print("Froebenius norm: {}".format(np.linalg.norm(HH-HH2,'fro')))

print("")
print("*** Mpmath calculations (very slow): *** ")
mp.dps = 40  # number of precision digits for mpmath
mHH = mp.matrix(HH)  # take previous atrix
mw, mVV = mp.eigh(mHH) # and do eigem decomposition

# Check rsults:
mHH2 = mVV*mp.diag(mw)*mVV.T
mdHH = mHH-mHH2
#Curiously I could not figure out how to determine abs(mdHH).max(),
hmax = mp.mpf(0)
for r in mdHH.tolist():
    for c in r:
        mc = c if c >= 0 else -c
        hmax = mc if mc > hmax else hmax

print("Elements differ by maximally {}".format(hmax))
print("Froebenius norm: {}".format(mp.norm(mdHH)))
# Sample output (differs because of randn()):
#
# *** Scipy calculations: ***
# Elements differ by maximally 6.48370246381e-14
# Froebenius norm: 4.90996840307e-13

# *** Mpmath calculations (very slow): *** 
# Elements differ by maximally 5.510129769479472693603452518229276614775e-39
# Froebenius norm: 3.772588954060141733111171961647528674136e-38
```

Comment: Do you know (I looked through the documentation quickly and didn't see anything) if I can use mp.eigh to compute only the largest (and smallest) eigenvalues?  (Likely with 2 separate calls.)  The scipy function eigh allows me to specify "only compute eigenvalues i..j."  Or at least, it only returns i..j, I assume it does not compute all eigenvalues first.

Comment: No, sorry - I have not seen in approaches to calculate only some eigenvalues to high precision (I haven't searched for it either). With the scipy function, I am also not sure, if it is mainly about calculating or not returning values.